# What should a header file look like for C++ projects?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, header-files

I’ve studied C, and now I’ve decided to switch to C++.

So, in C, I used `#ifndef` `#endif` in my header files. Should I use the same commands in C++? Or are there some alternatives?

Comment: Include guards are the same in C and C++.

Comment: the preprocessor works the same way, yes you will still need header guards.

Comment: _"Or there are some alternatives?"_ -  C++20 [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) would possibly be an alternative.

Comment: `#pragma once` is great, too

Comment: Of course you can use. Take a minute to study this document: [#ifdef and #ifndef directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-ifdef-and-hash-ifndef-directives-c-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the preprocessor works *(mostly)* the same way, so you should still use preprocessor directives to guard against including the same code more than once.

Any differences in functionality between the preprocessor in C and C++ are likely to be edge cases that are unlikely to be relevant at your current learning level.

Answer (score 0):

The file/header relationship is identical in C and C++.

foo.h:

```
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE
#define SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE

// your declarations (and certain types of definitions) here

#endif
```

The C++ preprocessor is essential the same when compared to it’s C counterpart. All directives will work in either language whether written in a header (.h) or a source file (.c, .cc, .cpp).

[Read more about the wonders of headers here!](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Commader_Quazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14968650/commader-quazar) is right and enough.

ALternatively you can substitute:

```
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE
#define SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE

// your declarations (and certain types of definitions) here

#endif
```

with:

```
#pragma once

// your declarations (and certain types of definitions) here
```

which lets you write 1 line of code instead of 3, and is less error prone (since in this case you don't have to worry about remembering to put `#endif` at the end of the file) however I personally prefer the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Besides macro guard explained by others, it would be nice to have a namespace and then your classes, structs, and all other functions go inside this namespace.